# Zeroes And Local Extremum Of Polynomials

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Prove that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial such that it has at least one zero and let $a$ and $b$ be the zeroes of polynomial such that $b \geq a$ and there is no $x$ with $x<a$,or $x>b$ such that $p(x)=0$, then $p(x)$ has no local Extremum for $x<a$ or $x>b$.

Comment: It's not clear from the post what you have tried, where did you get stuck (technically there is no question).

Comment: I don't know how to start so I haven't posted my try.

Comment: Try plotting $x(x-1)((x-2)^2+0.1)$

Comment: Thanks I got my answer